# CoreML updatable Model with multiple Loss Functions

Tags: coreml

I have a Neural Network that takes sensor data as input and produces eight binary classification outputs. I want to train that Neural Network with CoreML directly on my device. Therefore I need to make the model updatable and set multiple loss functions (one for each output). When I try to compile that model I get the following error message:

```
Error Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=3 "Error reading protobuf spec. validator error: This model has more than one loss layers specified, which is not supported at the moment." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error reading protobuf spec. validator error: This model has more than one loss layers specified, which is not supported at the moment.}
```

Now my question is: Is it possible to define multiple loss functions for an updatable CoreML model? If so, how? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the error message is very clear: a model with more than one loss layer is not supported. So the answer at this time is, no, it is not possible to have multiple loss layers per model.

Your error (emphasis is mine):

> This model has **more than one loss layers** specified, **which is not supported** at the moment."

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! Yeah I figured that, I just wanted to ask if there is any alternative way. What made me hope a little is, that I read online (i.e. https://machinethink.net/blog/coreml-training-part4/) that it is possible to specify multiple loss functions and additionally that the API docs for coremltools often mention the plural "loss_layers"

Comment: A MLModel can have multiple loss functions, but only a single loss layer as far as I understand.

Comment: could you maybe elaborate this a little further? Do you mean I could define multiple loss functions on the same output? Or how would I define multiple loss functions for my model?

Comment: A function typically takes parameters, does something with them and returns a result. You can have as many functions as you please, but the loss layer needs to return a single result which could be a tuple etc.

Comment: yeah but how would I do that? I can only set `set_categorical_cross_entropy_loss` of the neural network and this leads to multiple loss layers. I really struggle with finding a definitive answer to my question if updating such a neural network is possible in CoreML. Is there any other official communication channel, other than the Apple Developer Forum? There, no one answers me.

Comment: I guess I would have to see what you are actually doing; hard to say without seeing any source code. You may consider just calculating the losses using metal performance shaders, that way there are no real limitations.